# SQLite Command?

Tags: xamarin, sqlite.net

I am trying to make a login page with xamarin

```
public bool Login(string Username, string Password)
    {
        Users _user = new Users();
        string mySelectQuery = "SELECT Name, Password FROM Users WHERE Name='" + Username + "' AND Password='" + Password + "'";

        var user = new SQLiteCommand(mySelectQuery);

        if (user != null)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

At SQLiteCommand part it gives an error.
The error is CS1729 Does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
I checked out on the internet but I didn't get it I am new at this.

Comment: `what is wrong with my code` ... we don't know this, because you never told us.  Please give us a hint about what the problem is.

Comment: What error are you seeing? What is the value of 'user'?

Comment: oh sorry, I edited it.

Comment: you should stop and read the docs on using SQLite.  Even if you fix the current error your code isn't going to work.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but... you shouldn't be storing passwords as cleartext in your database (your query is accessing passwords directly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use SQLiteCommand class, and contain one arguments, it should be SQLiteConnection, here is sample that about this:

```
public bool Login(string Username, string Password)
    {

        string dbName = "Data Source=searchindex.db";
        string mySelectQuery = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Users WHERE Name='" + Username + "' AND Password='" + Password + "'";

        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(dbName);
        SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con);
        cmd.CommandText = mySelectQuery;

        var count = cmd.ExecuteScalar<int>();
        if (count>0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I just fixed the problem :)